# show that there exits a analytic cube root of a function on a domain

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that $f(z)=e^z+\frac{1}{(z-1)^3}+\frac{1}{(z+1)^6}$ has an analytic cube root on $\mathbb C$-{1,-1}.

The usual way is to pick up $ z_0 \notin \mathbb C$-{1,-1}, and $\forall z \in \mathbb C$-{1,-1}, let $\gamma_{z_0}^z$ be any curve that does not go through {1,-1}, then we can define $g(z)=e^{\frac{1}{3}\int_{\gamma _{z_0}^z}\frac{f'}{f}}$. To show g is analytic is to show g is well defined, or in other words, show $\frac{1}{3}\int_{\gamma }\frac{f'}{f}$ is a multiple of 2$\pi i, \space$ for any closed curve $\gamma$ with endpoint $z_0$ . The problem here is that although the number of poles (considering the multiplicity) of $f$ is a multiple of three, but f has two zeros in $\mathbb C$-{1,-1}. So by argument principle, I cannot see  $\frac{1}{3}\int_{\gamma }\frac{f'}{f}$ is a multiple of 2$\pi i, \quad$ for any closed curve $\gamma$ with endpoint $z_0$

Can anyone give me some ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you count the zeros? If any zero of $f$ has an order that is not a multiple of $3$, then $f$ _cannot_ have an analytic cube root. Are you sure it's an addition? $$e^z\cdot \frac{1}{(z-1)^3(z+1)^6}$$ looks more likely for an exercise (although, a bit trivial then).

Comment: @Daniel Fischer   Well, it is a qualifying exam question in 2012. It is a plus in the text sample. I guess the way to do it is to specify how to choose such a curve from $z_0$ to any z, but I've no idea because I just took advantage of wolfram to find the two zeros, which is not obvious at all by bare hands. –

Comment: Okay, I just verified that $f$ does not have an analytic cube root on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{-1,1\}$. Perhaps it said that it had an analytic cube root on $\mathbb{C}\setminus [-1,1]$?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer, but even if the change is accepted, one has to deal with the zero points of $f$ unless one specifies how to define the curve $\gamma \space$ from $z_0$ to $z$

Comment: Yes. But as written, it's wrong, if the domain is changed, it may have a chance to be true.

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer, yeah, I think so. I don't believe the question is doable in a qualifying exam, because in any case one has to figure out the zero points, which is impossible with bare hands. I guess the professor made a mistake and took it for granted that there was no zero points.

Comment: Or it was a trick question, and the examinee was supposed to see that it doesn't have an analytic cube root on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{-1,1\}$. That is doable with bare hands. By the way, $\mathbb{C}\setminus [-1,1]$ doesn't work either, I'm almost sure. The zero in $(-\infty,-1)$ is pretty certainly also simple.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer,  But how can one count the number of zeros of $f$? Do you have some other methods to disprove the fact that $f$ has a cube root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a meromorphic function $f \not\equiv 0$ defined on a domain $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ has a meromorphic $k$-th root, then the multiplicity of all zeros and poles of $f$ must be a multiple of $k$ (if $U$ is simply connected, that is also sufficient).

The given function

$$f(z) = e^z + \frac{1}{(z-1)^3} + \frac{1}{(z+1)^6}$$

is real ($f(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}$), and its only two poles are at $-1$ and $1$. For real $x < 1$, the summand $\frac{1}{(x-1)^3}$ is negative, and the summands $\frac{1}{(z+1)^6}$ and $e^z$ are positive. Since the negative summand vanishes of lower order than the positive summands, $f(x)$ is negative for negative $x$ of large absolute value. Since the pole at $-1$ is of even order, $f(x)$ is positive for real $x$ close to $-1$, and $f(x) < 0$ for $x$ close to $1$ but smaller than $1$. Thus $f$ has a zero $x_1$ in the interval $(-1,1)$ [at $\approx 0.145$], and a zero $x_2$ in the ray $(-\infty,-1)$ [at $\approx -5.760$]. It is easy to see that $f'(x) < 0$ for $-1 < x < 1$, and one can check that $f'(x_2) > 0$.

So the two known zeros [$f$ might have further non-real zeros] are simple, and $f$ cannot have an analytic cube root on any domain containing either of them. In particular, $f$ cannot have an analytic cube root on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{1,-1\}$ nor on $\mathbb{C}\setminus [-1,1]$. If $f$ has no further zeros, or all further zeros have multiplicity divisible by $3$, then $f$ has an analytic cube root on $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,1]$, however.

Comment: http://www.math.purdue.edu/academic/grad/oldExams/all/MA530_JAN12.pdf   Problem 6 in the qualifying exam above is the origional question, so I don't quite think the question is wrong.

Comment: Well, the exam problem is wrong. The function has simple zeros in the specified domain, hence cannot have an analytic cube root. It was either a mistake by the poser, or a trick question.